# Using progress bar with handler

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable, android-progressbar

Is there a way to use progress bar with handler? I have the code below and I would like to include a progress bar that would "count down" the delay until the next loop. (in this case 2000ms).

```
private boolean started = false;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {        
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Random random = new Random();
        int i = random.nextInt(2 - 0 + 1) + 0;
        random_note.setImageResource(image[i]);
        if(started) {
            start();
        }
    }
};

public void stop() {
    started = false;
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

public void start() {
    started = true;
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);        
}
```

Comment: Start your loader dialog in the run method, stop it in the stop?

Comment: yes, it is possible to use a Handler with a ProgressBar

Comment: i dont really understand what you mean please can you be more specific

Comment: Nui Chai - Yes, exactly.

The code as it is is looping the run method every 2000ms. I would like a progress bar, showing the remaining time until the next loop.

Answer (score 0):

Class level:

```
ProgressDialog asycdialog;
```

Definition (in onCreate()):

```
asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
asycdialog.setMessage("Working");
asycdialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
asycdialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
asycdialog.setCancelable(false);
```

in your start method:

```
asycdialog.show();
```

in your stop method:

```
asycdialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think I have to do this with a progress bar. To be more clear: My code (above) is randomly showing the pictures every 2 seconds. I would like a progress bar showing (countdown) the remaining time until the next picture would show up.

Comment: You can use `Asycdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);` with `Asycdialog.setMax(someInt);` and   `Asycdialog.incrementProgressBy(1);` also `.setProgress();` can come handy.

Answer (score 0):

i dont really get what you  mean but you can use a handler this way to upgrade a progressBar from the backGroud thread

```
private ProgressBar mProgressBar
    private Handler handle = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public  void handleMessage(Message msg){

        super.handleMessage(msg);
        mProgressBar.setProgress(msg.arg1);

    }



};
```

and to send update from another thread

```
Message msg = handle.obtainMessage(null,intWhat, mProgressionValur, 0);
                      handle.sendMessage(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Show progress and dismiss after some time :

```
 mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
 mProgressDialog.setMessage("loading info...");
 mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
 mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
 mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
 mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
 mProgressDialog.show();

   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, 3000);
```